# Flutter: change state when dragging

Tags: flutter, user-interface, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

I have a color with a certain opacity, and i would like the opacity to change if a Draggable child is moved to the right. The code I have currently looks like this:

```
Scaffold(
              appBar: TopAppBar(
                title: 'Discovery',
                hasActions: true,
              ),
              body: BlocBuilder<UserDiscoveryBloc, UserDiscoveryState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is UserDiscoveryLoading) {
                    return Center(child: Text('Loading...'));
                  } else if (state is UserDiscoveryLoaded) {
                    return (state.users.isEmpty)
                        ? Center(
                            child: Text("No users found"),
                          )
                        : SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  InkWell(
                                    onDoubleTap: () {
                                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/users',
                                          arguments: state.users[0]);
                                    },
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                                              1.4,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      child: Stack(
                                        children: [
                                          Draggable(
                                            child: DiscoveryUserCard(
                                              user: state.users[0],
                                              imageUrlIndex:
                                                  state.imageUrlIndex,
                                            ),
                                            feedback: Transform.rotate(
                                              angle: math.pi * 2,
                                              child: Stack(
                                                children: [
                                                  DiscoveryUserCard(
                                                    user: state.users[0],
                                                    imageUrlIndex:
                                                        state.imageUrlIndex,
                                                  ),
                                                  //a green check mark positioned on the top right corner
                                                  Positioned(
                                                    top: 20,
                                                    left: 0,
                                                    child: Icon(
                                                      Icons.check,
                                                      //green with 50 percent opacity
                                                      color: Colors.green
                                                          .withOpacity(
                                                              likeOpacity),
                                                      size: 120,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            childWhenDragging: (...),
                                            onDragEnd: (drag) {...}
                                            onDragUpdate: (drag) {
                                              //as drage delta increases the opacity of the green check mark increases
                                              if (drag.delta.dx > 0) {
                                                print(
                                                    'like opacity is ${10 * (likeOpacity = drag.delta.dx / MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)}');
                                                setState(() {
                                                  (likeOpacity = drag.delta.dx /
                                                          MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                              .size
                                                              .width) *
                                                      1000;
                                                });
                                              }
                                            },
                                          ),


//below this is irrelevant, its just the rest of my screen.




                                          //set a positioned row on the bottom of buttons
                                          Positioned(
                                            bottom: 0,
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width,
                                              child: Row(
                                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                                    MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                children: [
                                                  //a circular transparent conatiner with a red circular border and a red x icon
                                                  Container(
                                                    height: 60,
                                                    width: 60,
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                              40),
                                                      border: Border.all(
                                                          color: Colors.red,
                                                          width: 1),
                                                    ),
                                                    child: IconButton(
                                                      icon: Icon(
                                                        Icons.close,
                                                        color: Colors.red,
                                                        size: 40,
                                                      ),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        context.read<
                                                            UserDiscoveryBloc>()
                                                          ..add(
                                                              UserDiscoverySwipeLeft(
                                                            receiver:
                                                                state.users[0],
                                                            sender: user,
                                                          ));
                                                      },
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    width: 20,
                                                  ),
                                                  Container(
                                                    height: 60,
                                                    width: 60,
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                              40),
                                                      border: Border.all(
                                                          color: Colors.purple,
                                                          width: 1),
                                                    ),
                                                    child: IconButton(
                                                      icon: PartiallyFilledIcon(
                                                        icon: Icons.people,
                                                        color: //primary color
                                                            Colors.purple,
                                                        size: 40,
                                                        filledPercentage:
                                                            (user.discoveriesRemaning /
                                                                    15)
                                                                .toDouble(),
                                                      ),
                                                      onPressed: () {},
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    width: 20,
                                                  ),
                                                  Container(
                                                    height: 60,
                                                    width: 60,
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      color: Colors.transparent,
                                                      borderRadius:
                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                              40),
                                                      border: Border.all(
                                                          color: Colors.green,
                                                          width: 1),
                                                    ),
                                                    child: IconButton(
                                                      icon: Icon(
                                                        Icons.check,
                                                        color: Colors.green,
                                                        size: 40,
                                                      ),
                                                      onPressed: () {},
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                                  Center(
                                    child: Container(
                                      child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
                                                .9,
                                        lineHeight:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                .05,
                                        percent: (user.discoveriesRemaning / 15)
                                            .toDouble(),
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                        progressColor:
                                            Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                  } else if (state is UserDiscoveryError) {
                    return Center(
                      child: Text("No users found error"),
                    );
                  } else if (state is UserDiscoveryEmpty) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              "Either your daily discovery limit has been reached, or you've gone through all the users. Come back tomorrow for more!",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          LinearPercentIndicator(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .9,
                            lineHeight:
                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .05,
                            percent: (user.discoveriesRemaning / 15).toDouble(),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                            progressColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else if (state is UserDiscoverySendMessageState) {
                    return DiscoveryMessageUserCard(
                        imageUrlIndex: 0, user: state.users[0]);
                  } else {
                    return Text('Somethings wrong, yo');
                  }
                },
              ),
            );
```

Im trying to turn the dx parameter into a usable value between 0.00 and 1.00, currently the state gets set to weird values like .0002. Anyone have ideas on what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: snippet contains unknown data. Are you trying to change drag object color opacity?

Comment: updated to show the opacity @YeasinSheikh

Comment: are we aware of the target position?  can you include a minimal snippet from scaffold

Comment: @YeasinSheikh further updated